# NodeJS - Redirecionamento para página de erro ao não conseguir acessar através de GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, redirecionamento

Gostaria de saber como fazer o redirecionamento para uma página de erro padrão, como uma página "not-found" quando ocorrer um erro do tipo **Cannot GET /rota1/pagina2/18**

Eu preciso que, quando o usuário tente acessar uma página como a de cima e não seja acessível através do método get, ele redirecione para uma página explicando o erro.

Acredito que seja através do Middleware, pois tem no arquivo erros.js algumas funções como:

```
exports.notfound = function(req,res,next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('not-found');
};
```

Comment: Estás usando express?

Answer (score 0):

O Express segue uma lista de prioridade nas rotas, ou seja, ele pega a url requisitada e tenta "encaixá-la" em todas as rotas possíveis na sua aplicação. O jeito mais simples de resolver é adicionar uma rota para tratar isso, desa forma:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Se você adicionar essa rota após todas as outras o Express irá pegar as requisições que não conseguiu "encaixar" em nenhuma outra rota e mandar para ela, retornando a página de erro 404.

A propósito, essa rota acima é gerada automaticamente quando se usa o express-generator para que você não tenha que se preocupar com esse tipo de coisa.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando uma rota "pega-tudo".

Esta rota deve ser a última rota declarada em sua lista de rotas, para poder funcionar corretamente.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ser implementada:

```
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404', { url: req.url });
});
```

Ou usando respostas em JSON.

```
//middleware express.json deve estar ativo
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({msg: "not found"});
});
```